# Execution for-loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

```
def search_for_element(L, char):
    for i in L:
        if i == char:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

When I run the function, it only outputs one statement on the screen.
So why is the for loop only executed once?

Answer (score 2):

`return` terminates the function, move `return False` to after the loop:

```
def search_for_element(L, char):
    for i in L:
        if i == char:
            return True
    return False
```

Or simply:

```
def search_for_element(L, char):
    return char in L
```

Although note the latter is not *exactly* equivalent, since it also tests identity (not just equality). This will only matter in rather unusual circumstance though, for example `numpy.NAN == numpy.NAN` is `False` but `numpy.NAN in [numpy.NAN]` is `True`.

So the one-liner alternative would be:

```
def search_for_element(L, char):
    return any(char == i for i in L)
```